# In serverless, readXlsxFile & XLSX npm packages are not working?

Tags: node.js, xlsx, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

When we converted serverful to serverless, the npm packages such as XLSX & readXlsxFile are not working. It's throwing error. It was working properly in serverful environment. Our backend technology is nodejsV16.15.1. Please help!

Comment: Are you using Windows, Mac or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe happening because the runtime incompatibility between the binaries generated on your machine and the runtime used by AWS Lambda (Amazon Linux 2).

Since you are working on a newer NodeJS environment, if you start utilizing `import` and `export` (ES6) syntax, then you have to configure the `"type": "module"` property of `package.json` files.

Another approach that may help you fix the problem is by making sure that the libraries you've used on the existing application contains libraries that were compatible with NodeJS 16.

Another approach that you can try, is to delete your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` files and run a `npm install` command on a machine compatible with lambda's runtime.